# Url's from CSV not passing to function

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-asyncio, smmry

I'm trying to pass Urls from a .csv to a function that will send requests to SMMRY api. The .csv has a column labeled 'url', and the API summarizes websites using SMMRY (https://smmry.com/) and asyncio. The smmrpy module creates an "article" object and while it can print the properties, I'm trying to past a list of URLs to the function and have it loop and print summarizations until complete

The problem is, the urls aren't being passed to the function.  Below is my code

```
import time
import csv
import asyncio
import smmrpy


s = smmrpy.SMMRPY("ABCDEFGHI")
with open('Dec1.csv') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for row in reader:
        URL = (row['url'])

    async def main():
        article = await s.get_smmry(URL)
        global contents
        contents = article.content
        #print(contents)
        print(article.keywords)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())

print(contents)
```

Comment: Did you intend `async def main` to be part of the `for row in reader` loop?  It isn't.

Comment: Honestly, i'm unsure if its supposed to be part of the for row in header loop or not.  I tried indenting and not indenting; the urls don't pass to it.

Comment: The gist is that you reassign `URL` each time through the for loop and only the final value gets used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test this, but try:

```
import time
import csv
import asyncio
import smmrpy


async def main():
    s = smmrpy.SMMRPY("ABCDEFGHI")
    with open('Dec1.csv') as csvFile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
        for row in reader:
            URL = (row['url'])

            article = await s.get_smmry(URL)
            contents = article.content
            print(contents)
            print(article.keywords)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: This is awesome.  It worked just as I want it to.  It stops running if one of the urls doesn't jive with the api, or the text of the article is too short.  Is there a way to code "If error...skip this url and go on to the next?

Comment: @MaxxABillion Also, if your intention was for loop iterations executed in parallel, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53487199/1600898).